# Is there a way to achieve an optional expression in a macro?

Tags: parsing, macros, rust

I have a macro that simplifies the parsing of enums from strings in the form:

```
enum_printer!(Bar { fun1["AB","CD"]; fun2[] });
```

To make it slightly easier to use, I would like to make the `[]` optional i.e. be able to specify

```
enum_printer!(Bar { fun1["AB","CD"]; fun2; fun3 });
```

Here's the code as it stands

```
use failure::Error;
use std::convert::TryFrom;

macro_rules! enum_printer {
    ($name:ident { $($enumeration:ident [$($v:expr),*]);* }) => {
        #[derive(Debug)]
        enum $name {
            $(
                $enumeration,
            )*
        }
        impl<'a> TryFrom<&'a str> for $name {
            type Error = Error;
            fn try_from(value : &'a str) -> Result<$name,Error> {
            match value {
                $(
                    stringify!($enumeration) 
                    $(
                        | $v
                    )*                        
                    => Ok($name::$enumeration),
                )*
                _ => Err(err_msg("Could not convert from string to"))
            }                
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I've attempted to modify the first line:

```
($name:ident { $($enumeration:ident [$($v:expr),*]?);* }) => {
```

```
error: no rules expected the token `;`
  --> src/main.rs:30:36
   |
30 | enum_printer!(Bar { fun1["AB","CD"]; fun2; fun3 });
   |                                    ^
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for the `?` is the same as one for `*` or `+`: you must surround the optional pattern like this `$( <pattern> )?`.

Example:

```
#![feature(macro_at_most_once_rep)]

macro_rules! foo {
    ( $( $e:expr )? ) => {
        $( $e )?
    }
}
```

In your example, you must write:

```
($name:ident {
    $(
        $enumeration:ident $(
            [$( $v:expr ),*]
        )? // optional parameter
    );* // possible multiple parameters
}) => {
```

(I split the line to be clearer)

Comment: With that change I get `error[E0658]: Using the `?` `macro Kleene operator for "at most one" repetition is unstable (see issue #48075)`. Also the generation part changes to a nested loop to `$(|$v)*`

Comment: @Ronnie Yes, this is a nightly feature. About the second part, that's another issue: that's up to you to generate a code valid with and without the optional part.

Comment: I have a macro that's used to generate a struct with methods. For one of the times I want to use the macro I want to add an additional method to the struct. So I was thinking I can add an optional expression, but I don't want to reference the expression that's passed into my macro, I just want to use it as a flag to include an expression (the definition of my method), how do I do that? Or is there a better way to do this in Rust?

Comment: @Boris I think that you should ask a separate question. I'm unsure of that you want.